# Set a limit to parallel tasks received by azure DownloadToStreamAsync

Tags: c#, azure, task-parallel-library

I have a bunch of files (about 10k) that I need to download from windows azure storage. In order for them to download in parallel instead of one at a time I'm using the blob DownloadToStreamAsync method which returns a Task object. I then set the task ContinueWith with a method that save the stream to a file.

Here is the code:

```
foreach (var File in ServerFiles)
{
    string sFileName = File.Uri.LocalPath.ToString();
    CloudBlockBlob oBlob = BiActionscontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sFileName.Replace("/" + Container + "/", ""));

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    BlobRequestOptions f = new BlobRequestOptions();
    Task downloadTask = oBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);

    downloadTask.ContinueWith((Task task) =>
    {
         ms.Position = 0;
         lock(lockObject)
         {
              using (FileStream file = new FileStream(ResultPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
              {
                   byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
                   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
              }
         }
         ms.Dispose();
    });
}
```

this code is part of a tool that runs on one of our servers (not on azure) - windows 2003 server. the problem is that on that server I get "The operation has timed out. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage on windows 2003 standard", so I figured it could be that a lot of files are making a request at the same time and chock the bandwidth.

So I was wondering, how could I limit the number of parallels that run at a time in such a scenario where I get the Task object from a third party library? and still queue the rest of the tasks coming in?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your system is getting hosed because of the following line of code `foreach (var File in ServerFiles)`. You would need to throttle here somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SemaphoreSlim` for this. Set it up with the number of concurrent requests you want to have and then use `await WaitAsync()` before starting each request, `Release()` after each request finishes, and finally wait for the remaining tasks.

Encapsulated in a helper method, it could look like this:

```
public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task> action, int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
{
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreeOfParallelism);

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        Func<T, Task> loopAction = async x =>
        {
            await action(x);
            semaphore.Release();
        };

        tasks.Add(loopAction(item));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Usage (with some changes to your code, mostly to simplify it and also to make it more asynchronous):

```
ServerFiles.ForEachAsync(async file =>
{
    string sFileName = File.Uri.LocalPath.ToString();
    CloudBlockBlob oBlob = BiActionscontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sFileName.Replace("/" + Container + "/", ""));

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    BlobRequestOptions f = new BlobRequestOptions();
    await oBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);

    ms.Position = 0;
    lock (lockObject)
    {
         using (var file = new FileStream(ResultPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
         {
              await ms.CopyToAsync(file);
         }
    }
});
```

An alternative implementation would use `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow. It knows how do all that's needed here, you just need to set it up:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task> action, int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
{
    var block = new ActionBlock<T>(
        action,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
        });

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        block.Post(item);
    }

    block.Complete();
    return block.Completion;
}
```